# React Native Android TabBar not hiding with style option

Tags: android, react-native

I faced with a problem on `Tab.Navigator` from `@react-navigation/native`

I use this code to hide and show TabBar

```
this.props.navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: true\false })
```

But when I set style to `Tab.Navigator`, `tabBarVisible` option stops working

```
tabBarOptions={{
  style: { transform: [{ scaleX: I18nManager.isRTL ? -1 : 1 }] }
}}
```

Is there any workaround on this problem?

My `RN` version is `18.2.0`

`@react-navigation/native` is `^6.0.10`

Answer (score 0):

please try to implement this in your code

```
  screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true/false, // make false if don't want to display toolbar
      }}
```